# Updated Typescript - Receiving Error on Combine Reducers Function TS2344

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, reducers

I'm still working my way through understanding TypeScript and I'm not sure what this is trying to tell me here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This code is receiving an object of reducer objects. When compiling my React/Ionic project, I'm now receiving the following error after updating underlying libraries:

**TypeScript error in .../src/data/combineReducers.ts(3,47):**

- Type 'R[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
- Type 'R[keyof R]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
- Type 'R[string] | R[number] | R[symbol]' is not assignable to type
  '(...args: any) => any'.
- Type 'R[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.  TS2344

```
[react-scripts]     1 | export function combineReducers<R extends any>(reducers: R) {
[react-scripts]     2 |   type keys = keyof typeof reducers;
[react-scripts]   > 3 |   type returnType = { [K in keys]: ReturnType<typeof reducers[K]> }
[react-scripts]       |                                               ^
[react-scripts]     4 |   const combinedReducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
[react-scripts]     5 |     const newState: returnType = {} as any;
[react-scripts]     6 |     const keys = Object.keys(reducers);
```

```js
export function combineReducers<R extends any>(reducers: R) {
  type keys = keyof typeof reducers;
  type returnType = { [K in keys]: ReturnType<typeof reducers[K]> }
  const combinedReducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
    const newState: returnType = {} as any;
    const keys = Object.keys(reducers);
    keys.forEach(key => {
      const result = reducers[key](state[key], action);
      newState[key as keys] = result || state[key];
    });
    return newState;
  }
  return combinedReducer;
};
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after `npm i typescript@3.8.3`

Answer (score 0):

An another complete solution is here:

function combineReducers<R extends { [key: string]: any }>(reducers: R)

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-react-conference-app/issues/50

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29872817)